# It it possible to to read using fscanf till EOF ? C

Tags: c

I'm writing function that reads names,last_names and numbers from txt file and saves them to structure. Variables in the file are arranged in this way

Name | Last Name | Number

My problem is that fscanf have problem with reading last number before EOF.

My code:

```
int load_phonebook_t(const char *filename, struct entry_t* p, int size)
{
   int a,i,ilosc=0;
   FILE *fp;
   if(filename==NULL || p==NULL || size<1)
   {
      return -1;
   }    
   fp=fopen(filename,"r");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
      return -2;
   }
   rewind(fp);
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      if(i==size-1)
      {
         a=fscanf(fp,"%s | %s | %d[^EOF]",(p+i)->name,(p+i)->last_name,&(p+i)->number);
      }
      else
      {
         a=fscanf(fp,"%s | %s | %d",(p+i)->name,(p+i)->last_name,&(p+i)->number);
      }
      if(a==3)
      {
         ilosc++;
      }
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return ilosc;
}
```

I tried using fscanf(fp,"%s | %s | %d[^EOF]") but it didn't work. I need an idea how to stop reading before EOF or how to read it correctly.

Edit:

Last few lines from my .txt file:

```
Annette | Bening | 378422705
George | C.Scott | 209747332
Burt | Lancaster | 568016673
Louis | Gossett Jr. | 528057525
```

Comment: Does your file include integers followed by the characters `[^EOF]`? Re-read the appropriate documentation for scanf family functions, paying attention to the description of the format argument, and to what they return. You can't just throw random things in and expect it to work.

Comment: Isn't `[^EOF]` anything that's not an `E`, `O`, or `F`? On most systems EOF is a condition not a character. If you're concerned about positioning, read in the data in chunks and write a proper parser. `scanf` is a crutch.

Comment: `%d[^EOF]` is certainly not doing what you think.  If this loop is simply supposed to read `size` number of lines, formatted into the fields of your structure, reporting back how many were read (assuming sometime soon you'll address the impending doom of buffer overflow against those unguarded `%s` specifiers), then do that. That's the problem to solve, not how to not-read into EOF. Frankly, this has the aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @WhozCraig I might describe what I want badly, but problem is still that I cannot read last number and I don't know why it isn't reading it. I assumed that this is happening due to EOF and I tried to find solution to it.

Comment: Are you saying the symptoms of your real problem are that the last line `fscanf` only reads *two* specified arguments? I.e. that final `fscanf` returns `2` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes.

Comment: @seltkirk can you post last few lines of your files?

Comment: `Gossett Jr.` is borking your subsequent `int` read. `Jr. | 528057525` is still in the input stream because the whitespace before it stopped the last name extraction. Actually *printing* the entries from your structure as you read them would show you this.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, I was looking at debugged and I didn't saw that it isn't reading Jr. Well, thanks for help.

Comment: To process `Louis Gosset Jr.`, you'll probably want to use `%19[^|]` or something similar (assuming the name buffer is `char [20]`), but that will capture leading and trailing spaces, which you'll probably want to remove. You might need to use the same notation for the first name field. Be aware that `scanf()` is one of the hardest functions to use correctly — especially with complex input formats. You're often better off using `fgets()` to read a line of data, and then using `sscanf()` to parse it. That way, you can make multiple passes over the data, if need be (and report better errors).

Answer (score 0):

Stopping at end of file with scanf is easy.

```
a=fscanf(fp,"%s | %s | %d",(p+i)->name,(p+i)->last_name,&(p+i)->number);

if (a != 3) {
     /* handle eof; */
     break;
}
```

There's a lot of stuff yet to do involving malformed files and reading the file once while growing your array, but hey baby steps man. You will reach that eof block on any IO or format error as well.